# Mouse drag re-triggers randomly

Tags: x11, gnome, mouse

I've a freshly installed Manjaro with Gnome 3.36.1. The problem I've been having is that whenever I'm dragging something with the left mouse button, the system randomly releases the mouse drag and then re-triggers it again immediately. This happens across all applications.

This is most noticeable when trying to select text with the mouse. The selection randomly resets and starts again in the position where the cursor is currently. I can't see any pattern with it, sometimes it happens every couple of seconds and sometimes it doesn't happen for a minute.

I have a Razer USB mouse that is working fine on the same machine on Windows.

What could be causing this or how could I start investigating what is causing it? I'm suspecting it might be some other process stealing the focus or some USB issue.

Comment: I'm also seeing the same problem on Manjaro/Gnome while using an Apple Magic Mouse, but not when using a cheap bluetooth Tecknet mouse. The Apple mouse used to work fine until a couple of days ago then it started exhibiting this strange behaviour while dragging, either selecting text or dragging a window. If you come up with a solution or any more information please add it here.

Comment: For the record I found out that this was caused by a malfunctioning mouse. The issue occurred in Windows as well but just not to the same extent.

Comment: I also discovered the source of my problems, it seems like there were two drivers competing for mouse control which was causing issues with drag. Sorting this out results in nice smooth dragging and control